Use VBA to create a specific set of different colors of multiple lines for all charts in a worksheet. Charts were created in excel rather than vba
I've tried the following bit it has no effect of any kind on any chart in my worksheet:
Sub GraphColors()
  Dim myChartObject As ChartObject
  Dim mySrs As Series

  For Each myChartObject In Sheets("Ib v Eb c Ec").ChartObjects
    For Each mySrs In myChartObject.Chart.SeriesCollection
      Select Case mySrs.Name
        Case "1"
          mySrs.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Case "2"
          mySrs.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        Case "3"
          mySrs.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        Case "4"
          mySrs.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Case "5"
          mySrs.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
      End Select
    Next
  Next
End Sub


Try mySrs.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(..)

Still no effect.  Changed Case "1" to Case "" Still no effect

Add Debug.Print mySrs.Name before Select Case and then check the output in VBE Immediate Window

Excuse my ignorance. How do I get the VBE Immediate Window to show?

never mind, found it

It's displaying the names of the lines of my graphs.

The reason i saw no change was that the colors I was setting were the default colors! Now the colors of five traces change; but only in one of the four graphs on my worksheet. How do I get them to change in all four?

one of the four graphs -- What's graphs? Is it a chart? Plese Edit your post to share a screenshot.

one of the 4 charts. My ignorance is compounded by an inability to add a screen shot.

Thanks for your help - I figured out the last part of my problem. In the Case "*" statement, the * is the name I assigned to a graph trace. The reason only one graph was updated is that my Case statements did not include the names of the traces on the other graph!
